# TableView and Combobox TableCell

Tags: javafx-8

I want to create a TableView with two Columns. The first one holds SimpleStringProperty from the Requirement Class. The second should hold a ComboboxTableCell with data from the Requirement Class. The Class is as following:

```
public class Requirement{

private SimpleStringProperty requirementTitle;
private ObservableList<Criteria> criteria = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
...getters and setters... }


public class Criteria{

private SimpleStringProperty criteriaTitle;
...getters and setters... }


public class CriteriaViewController {


@FXML
private TableView<Requirement> criteriaTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Requirement, String> requirementColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Requirement, String> criteriaColumn;

public void initializeTable(){
    requirementColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("requirementTitle"));
    criteriaColumn.setCellValueFactory(???);
    criteriaColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(???));
}
```

The problem im facing is how can i fill the Combobox with the Data from the Observablelist from the Requirement class? I would be really thankful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: `ComboBoxTableCell` is not the right control to use to display a list of things from the model class. A `ComboBoxTableCell` really displays a single variable from the model class, that can take on a fixed number of values: the items in the combo box will be the same for all the cells in the column. If you want to use a combo box with different items in each cell, you need to implement the cell yourself: however it is not really clear what you want to do here. What does the *selected item* in the combo box represent, in terms of the `Requirement` class?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The ComboBox will have different items for each cell (2-4 items). Lets say for example the we have a requirement performance. Then i would have a selection of criterias. The criterias are fulfilled, poor, not fulfilled. So these items would represent a grading / rate system where the user selects one for each Requirement to give a rating. I hope this is more understandable.

Comment: You missed my point. I understand that you want different items in each combo box. My point is that your model isn't sufficient for describing a combo box. The data needed for a combo box are a list, *along with a selected item in that list*. Most of the time a combo box displays just one item - not the entire list. Your `Requirement` class doesn't contain the information as to which item should be displayed (it only contains the information as to which items should be in the popup).